# How to fix regular expression for evaluating if mathematical expression is valid

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to build a simple calculator in c# and am using a method to check if the expression is valid before sending it to the "Solve-method". But I can't understand why the check always return false.

```
bool validExpression = Regex.IsMatch(textBoxValue, @"^(\d+([,]\d+)?[*\/+-])+(\d+([,]\d+)?)$");
```

I am trying to match expressions like: 2,4+3/2,1*22.
All online regex testers I have tried tells me that my regex works but c# disagrees with me as it always return false.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], when I tried your pattern and your example string, it succeeds.

Comment: For the expression provided, using a string instead of `textBoxValue` I got a `true` result.

Comment: I will have to caution you though, there are many ways to trip up this pattern, so this will only work if you have a very limited set of allowed formats that you want to handle. For instance, this doesn't match, `"-3*4"`. You probably want to build a real tokenizer and parser instead.

Comment: Sooner or later you'll have to stop relying solely on a single regex and start *parsing* instead. At that point, it's usually a good idea to sit down and *formalize* the grammar of the language you want to accept.

Comment: And I hope your evaluator for your example expression ends up with 33.8285714...... as your result? I ask because you have both + and * in there, and if you don't get association and priorities right, you'll get the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all input, I feel really stupid as I had worked on this problem for hours and it never worked as expected. I don't know why but after closing down Visual Studio and rebooting the computer the regex worked. 
I realize there is some flaws in the expression but for my simple needs it is enough.